# Content rating control is always hidden

Tags: kentico

I've added the following code to the selected transformation of a News List webpart:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/CMSAdminControls/ContentRating/RatingControl.ascx" TagName="RatingControl" TagPrefix="cms" %>

<cms:RatingControl ID="elemRating" runat="server" Enabled="true" RatingType="Stars"  ExternalValue='
<%# Convert.ToString(CMS.GlobalHelper.ValidationHelper.GetDouble(Eval("DocumentRatingValue"), 0)/((CMS.GlobalHelper.ValidationHelper.GetDouble(Eval("DocumentRatings"), 0) == 0?1:CMS.GlobalHelper.ValidationHelper.GetDouble(Eval("DocumentRatings"), 1)))) %>' />
```

The rest of the selected transformation is the same as the default.

According to the Kentico [documentation](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html) this should add the webpart to the details page of a news item.

For some reason the input tag is getting rendered as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="p$lt$zoneContent$pageplaceholder$pageplaceholder$lt$News$NewsList$repItems$ctl00$ctl00$elemRating$RatingControl$elemRating_RatingExtender_ClientState" id="p_lt_zoneContent_pageplaceholder_pageplaceholder_lt_News_NewsList_repItems_ctl00_ctl00_elemRating_RatingControl_elemRating_RatingExtender_ClientState" value="0">
```

note the `type="hidden"` attribute. This causes the control not to render and I'm not sure where to fix this.

Comment: The hidden input is only there to store the value. Are you sure that directly below that isn't an anchor tag with a bunch of spans within it? Those rely on CSS classes referenced in the CMSDesk.css. Without those, no stars are even going to display.

Comment: Yeah you are right. It was a CSS issue. If you put this in the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment. The  is actually just used to store the value. Below that, it renders some extra content that will not display unless some CSS classes are carried over from the CMSDesk.css.

You can either copy the necessary CSS classes into your own CSS, or just import the CMSDesk.css file where necessary to make sure the rating elements are displaying.